# How to create virtual machine environments?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

I want to create a number of virtual machine environments for testing new beta releases - Windows 7, VS2010, Windows Server 2008 and so on. My host OS is Windows XP. What is the best way of going about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a free solution, [download Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6).

Install it and then it should be straight forward - You treat each and every virtual machine as its own physical computer, so put in the CD/DVD or mount the ISO (or mount the VHD) and away you go.

If you don't mind paying, I highly recommend [VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/index.html), at the end of the day, you will be able to accomplish the same, but Workstation has so many features (such as snapshots) that I just could not do without.

Comment: You can also still use the free VMware Player, although it's a bit more complex to create a new VM.

Answer (score 4):

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is a nice **cross-platform**, *free* application which allows you to do this.  You can emulate nearly every operating system under one-another.  The full list of compatible guest operating systems can be found [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes).

Once you install the program, you can create individual "virtual machines" for each computer.  You can make each have it's own hard-disk (or multiple ones), each with bridged networking and USB device support.

Another nice thing is that you can load up ISO files into the virtual CD-Rom driver, which is much quicker than conventional "load from disk" (most hard-drives have a higher throughput than all CD/DVD drives).